# Can I omit чтобы to express the purpose?

Tags: грамматика

I found the following sentence:

> У меня болит голова, и я иду в аптеку купить лекарство.

So far, all the sentences that I have seen use чтобы, in order to express the purpose. For example,

> Я пойду в магазин, чтобы купить газету.

But the sentence above doesn't use чтобы. It also doesn't use и to connect the two verbs (идти and купить), so I feel like the sentence is incomplete grammar-wise. Why does it lack чтобы and what is the rule of using vs avoiding it?